# OpenXava Impossible to execute Add files action Member not found in model

Tags: openxava

I'm experimenting with OpenXava files stereotype and embedded class and finding a strange error. First of all, if I create a record and attach a bunch of files to it ***before*** saving it for the first time, everything works. If I, however, first create a record (Temple), leave everything in the embedded record (Library) blank, save (saves successfully, it says), then go back to edit it, I get the following message: "Impossible to execute Add files action: Member library.documents not found in model Temple"

I have not been able to find anything useful via google on this.

Is this something I'm doing wrong or an error in OpenXava library.

I'm using: OpenXava version 5.1.1
Tomcat that comes with it: Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.50
Oracle 11g

Here's my Temple and the inner Library class:

```
package org.openxava.zen.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.openxava.annotations.*;

@Entity
public class Temple 
{
    @Id @Column(length=3) @GeneratedValue @ReadOnly
    private int id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String name;

    @Stereotype("IMAGES_GALLERY")
    private String photos;

    @Column
    private String address;

    @Embedded
    private Library library;

    @Embeddable
    public static class Library
    {
        @Stereotype("FILES")
        @Column(length=32)
        private String documents;

        public Admittance getAdmittance() {
            return admittance;
        }

        public void setAdmittance(Admittance admittance) {
            this.admittance = admittance;
        }

        @Column
        private Admittance admittance;

        public enum Admittance {MEMBERS_ONLY, COMMUNITY, EVERYONE};

        public String getDocuments() 
        {
            return documents;
        }

        public void setDocuments(String documents) 
        {
            this.documents = documents;
        }
    }


    public Library getLibrary() {
        return library;
    }

    public void setLibrary(Library library) {
        this.library = library;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos(String photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Full stacktrace:

> Dec 01, 2014 4:09:46 PM org.directwebremoting.util.CommonsLoggingOutput info
>   INFO: Exec: Module.request()
>   Dec 01, 2014 4:09:46 PM org.openxava.model.impl.MapFacadeBean validate
>   WARNING: WARNING!: Member library.documents of Temple not validated: Type unkown (property, reference, collection)
>   Dec 01, 2014 4:09:46 PM org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager manageRegularException
>   SEVERE: Member library.documents not found in model Temple
>   org.openxava.util.XavaException: Member library.documents not found in model Temple
>       at org.openxava.model.impl.MapFacadeBean.convertSubmapsInObject(MapFacadeBean.java:1675)
>       at org.openxava.model.impl.MapFacadeBean.setValues(MapFacadeBean.java:1337)
>       at org.openxava.model.impl.MapFacadeBean.setValues(MapFacadeBean.java:198)
>       at org.openxava.model.MapFacade.setValues(MapFacade.java:635)
>       at org.openxava.actions.AddFileToFilesetAction.execute(AddFileToFilesetAction.java:27)
>       at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(ModuleManager.java:493)
>       at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.executeAction(ModuleManager.java:401)
>       at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.execute(ModuleManager.java:358)
>       at org.apache.jsp.xava.execute_jsp._jspService(execute_jsp.java:196)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
>       at org.openxava.web.servlets.Servlets.getURIAsStream(Servlets.java:66)
>       at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.getURIAsStream(Module.java:205)
>       at org.openxava.web.dwr.Module.request(Module.java:64)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
>       at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
>       at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
>       at org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
>       at org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
>       at org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
>       at org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is addressed in OpenXava forums:
https://sourceforge.net/p/openxava/discussion/419690/thread/fde016f3/